# Prove that certain elements are not in some ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have the following question:

Is there a simple way to prove that

$x+1 \notin \langle2, x^2+1\rangle_{\mathbb{Z}[x]}$ and

$x-1 \notin \langle2, x^2+1\rangle_{\mathbb{Z}[x]}$

without using the fact that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle2, x^2+1\rangle$ is an integral domain?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Actually it's a field, isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z}[i]$

Comment: @Lana What do you mean by that notation?

Comment: @Lana But $x^2 + 1$ already splits over $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thinking about it the most right thing is to DEFINE what I wrote ($\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{2Z}[i]$) as that quotient ring, just because otherwise you have to speak of polynomials with $i$ as indeterminates, which makes no sense to me. The only other possibility is to embed $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{2Z}$ in a larger field which contains $i$ and then to define it as the smallest subfield that contains both $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{2Z}$ and $i$.

Comment: For what concerns the splitting stuff, I made a mistake writing one thing for another, but the answer above is better.

Comment: @Lana and Lena The ideal isn't even prime, much less maximal. $(x+1)^2$ is in it, but $x+1$ is not. The quotient is *not* a domain...

Comment: Well, you're right: now I have to find where it fails to make the quotient separatedly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First a comment: it looks like the goal of the problem is to show that $(2,x^2+1)$ *isn't* a prime ideal (and hence the quotient *isn't* a domain), because $(x+1)^2=x^2+1+2x$ is *in* the ideal, and we hope to show that $x+1$ isn't in the ideal.

If $x+1\in (2,x^2+1)$, then we would be able to find two polynomimals in $\Bbb Z[x]$, say $a$ and $b$, such that $x+1=2a+(x^2+1)b$.

Looking at the equation mod 2, you get $x+1=(x^2+1)\overline{b}$, where all the terms are in $\Bbb F_2[x]$. But since $\Bbb F_2[x]$ is a domain, the degrees on both sides have to match. If $\deg(b)>0$, then the degree of the right hand side would be at least 3, and even if the degree of $b$ were 0, the right hand side would have degree 2. It is impossible then, for such an expression to be equal to $x+1$. By this contradiction, we conclude $x+1$ is not in the ideal.

Finally, you can note that $x+1$ is in the ideal iff $x-1$ is, since $x-1+2=x+1$.

Thus we have shown that $(2,x^2+1)$ is not a prime ideal, and it isn't even a semiprime ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the simplest way *to try* to address these questions is tro try to characterize the elements in the ideal. In this case

$$f(x)\in\langle 2,x^2+1\rangle\iff f(x)=2g(x)+(x^2+1)h(x)\;,\;\;g(x),h(x)\in\Bbb Z[x]$$

and this means that any non-zero element in the ideal has either all its coefficients even and/or it is a multiple of $\,x^2+1\,$ , and this means either $\,f\,$ has **all** its coefficients even or its degree is at least two

Well, since neither $\,x-1\,,\,x+1\,$ fulfills the above neither belongs to the ideal.

Answer (score -1):

$x-1 \in I \implies x-1=2p+q(x^2+1) \implies q=0$ (reasoning on degree) so that you have $x-1=2p$ which is clearly impossible.

Comment: I don't quite see why it is trivial that $q=0$.

Comment: Reduce mod 2 to get that if q has a term of zero degree it has to be odd, but then you can't have the cancelation of the $x^2$ term since $2p$ has obviously only even coefficients (this should be enough to convince you)

Comment: I was not lacking convincing argument why it was true. I was just not seeing it to be as easy as the answer made it seem.

Comment: Maybe the degree of obviousness depends on your experience and smartness too, so that you're right, it's always better to be more precise.(Obviously is a general fact, that "your" is not directed to you)

Comment: @Lana I think Tobias is getting at something like this: if $p=x^2$ and $q=-2$, then $2p+q(x^2+1)=-2$. The degree of -2 is less than 2, but it didn't imply that $q=0$. A person reading this without the mental jumps you are making would get stuck, so it would improve the answer to have a little more scaffolding.

Comment: Sure man, you're right: I realized that it could be not obvious that we're assuming without loss of generality that terms of degree greater or equal to 2 cancel themselves reciprocally.. But what I've added should clear the situation